# ElasticSearch datatype for a concrete value

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I've encountered following error message when I've set `Nested` data type for such input `['abc', 'def', 'ghi']`.

> object mapping for [tags] tried to parse field [null] as object, but
>   found a concrete value

Please let me know which kind of datatype should I set for `concrete value`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array of **strings** then use **text** datatype. if it's an array of objects use **Nested** datatype. See reference https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html. the reason you've received this error it's because you've tried to index array of strings (concrete values) as **Nested** datatype but **Nested** datatype expects to see an object and not a string (concrete value). Also check this out https://discuss.elastic.co/t/object-mapping-for-configurationitems-configuration-state-tried-to-parse-field-state-as-object-but-found-a-concrete-value/80995